# What is bearer token or basic token metioned in HTTP Authorization header?

Tags: rest, security, http, http-headers

I can see HTTP Authorization headers used like this:

```
Authorization: Basic some_string
Authorization: Bearer some_string
Authorization: MAC some_string
```

I assume `some_string` is some sort of token used for Authentication purpose. So what does these words like `Basic`, `Bearer` and `MAC` before token means? Are they some types of tokens? If they are some types, what are all the possible types/values can be there in HTTP Authorization header?

Additionally, what are the use cases for each of these types? Any link or explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: Registry of authentication schemes: <http://www.iana.org/assignments/http-authschemes/http-authschemes.xhtml> Specification of HTTP authentication: <http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc7235.html>

Comment: In addition, some OAuth2 flows use the `Authorization` header for transport of OAuth2 tokens; see: http://self-issued.info/docs/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-bearer.html#authz-header